# CKAN Spatial Search Widget not returning any result

Tags: ckan

I've added Spatial Search Widget to CKAN setup. I can see the map on the dataset listing page and on the left panel of the individual dataset page. However, when I 'search' using the map on the listing page, it returned no result and the map on individual page does show the GEO location. You can see from the screenshots. Any idea why this happens?

[image: Search by map returns nothing]
[image: Location marked on the individual page]

Cheers,
Vic

Comment: Which spatial search backend are you using? (The spatial search backend is determined by `ckanext.spatial.search_backend` in your .ini file.)